# 2D fitting using matlab?

Tags: matlab, 2d, best-fit, geometry-surface

This may sound like an old question. I thought I know the code, but running it does not give me expected values.

My problem is:

target function: `f = C / (x ^ p * y ^ q)`

(if you know something about machining, you can tell that this is the Taylor's tool life equation)

`x` and `y` are independent variables; `f` is dependent variable; `C`, `p` and `q` are coefficients.

I have three sets of `([x, y], f)` values as the following, please see "exp_result".

And I am looking for a best-fit surface for the three sets of values.

Here's my code:

By running it I get:

- `C  1.224E4`
- `p  2.025`
- `q  5.688`

So the equation of my best-fit surface is `T = 1.224E4 / (x ^ 2.025 * y ^ 5.688)`.

However, at least I found that this equation fits the three sets of data better:
`T = 9.83E7 / (x ^ 3.39 * y ^ 2.63)`.

By plugging in the `x`'s and `y`'s, I get far closer `f`'s using this equation. Anyone has an idea where I did wrong?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

```
exp_result = [153.6   0.51  22.47; 192.01  0.61  6.52; 230.42  0.51  5.58];

f_exp = fittype('C / (x ^ p * y ^ q)', 'coefficients', {'C', 'p', 'q'}, 'independent', {'x', 'y'}, 'dependent', {'f'});

f_exp_coef = fit([exp_result(:,1), exp_result(:, 2)], exp_result(:, 3),f_exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The scale of C is very different from the other two parameters, making it harder to fit.

(1) either by giving a closer initial guess

or (2) rewrite the function in log term

log(f) = log(C) - p*log(x) - q*log(y) or f' = c - p*x' - q*y'

use [log(f) log(x) log(y)], you can obtain c, p, q which are in the same range [1 10], this hopefully give you a better fit.